# Using AnimationFactory.Java outToLeftAnimation

Tags: java, android

I am using a method from the creator of AnimationFactory.Java. I can not figure out how to implement two of these methods.

I would like to slide out one fragment and slide in another one.

Here is the method that I am trying to use:

```
 * Slide animations to hide a view by sliding it to the left.
 *
 * @param duration the animation duration in milliseconds
 * @param interpolator the interpolator to use (pass {@code null} to use the {@link AccelerateInterpolator} interpolator)
 * @return a slide transition animation
 */
public static Animation outToLeftAnimation(long duration, Interpolator interpolator) {
    Animation outtoLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  -1.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
    );
    outtoLeft.setDuration(duration);
    outtoLeft.setInterpolator(interpolator==null?new AccelerateInterpolator():interpolator);
    return outtoLeft;
}


 * Slide animations to enter a view from right.
 *
 * @param duration the animation duration in milliseconds
 * @param interpolator the interpolator to use (pass {@code null} to use the {@link AccelerateInterpolator} interpolator)
 * @return a slide transition animation
 */
public static Animation inFromRightAnimation(long duration, Interpolator interpolator) {

    Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  +1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
    );
    inFromRight.setDuration(duration);
    inFromRight.setInterpolator(interpolator==null?new AccelerateInterpolator():interpolator);
    return inFromRight;
}
```

Anyone know how to use these methods?

Thanks.